# call filter in Symfony with parameter

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Is possible call filter in Symfony in backend (admin generator) with parameters? In address URL is null. In session are parameters, but how can i this use for calling? For example

**http://www.myaddress.com/backend.php/users/filter?age=18**

Comment: This question is not clear. Are you using the admin generator and trying to filter not using the the generated form filter? If yes, you should try using POST, because that's the way /filter expects the filter command.

Comment: what do you mean with parameters? Do you mean the value of the fields you are able to filter by, or you mean to add some additional parameters to the query? Please detail your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the manual - especially the links and routing chapter - this will help you determine how you create / manage urls for accessing data in your application :

http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/09-Links-and-the-Routing-System

Comment: this isnt it. for example: http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/12 i would like open backend with filter public=no, for example: http://mysite.com/backend.php/filter?public=no